# Adverse effects of urban growth on old astronomy observatories? Need article/book

Tags: light-pollution, observatory

I am looking to get some information on the adverse effects of urban growth/light pollution on the oldest/traditional observatories of the world (europe).

Can anyone recommend me books or articles to read?